# Python cannot copy item to list

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to copy items to a list, but it always adds just links.

This is what I tried:

1:

```
list1 = []
list2 = [1]
list1.append(list2)
```

2.

```
list1 = []
list2 = [1]
list1 += [list2]
```

3.

```
list1 = []
list2 = [1]
list1 = list1 + [list2]
```

When I modify list2 after that, list1 always changes, too.

Python version: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

How do I append to a list without appending just a reference.

Comment: You should consider not using `l1` and `l2` as variable names. The `l` looks too much like `1`. This actually threw me off when I was reading your post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `list1.extend(list2)`.  See the documentation for more information: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on what you expect the result to be.

1. If you're looking to append the entire list as a single element, you need to use `list2[:]` to make a (shallow) copy, e.g.:

   `list1 += [list2[:]]`
2. If, on the other hand, you're looking to append `list2`'s *elements* to `list1`, then you're looking for

   `list1.extend(list2)`

Comment: +1 for an answer that works. `list.extend` is a lot faster, though

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, because it creates a new list, but it works:

```
list1 = list1 + list2
```